# Strange malloc behavior won't allow more that 2GB memory allocation on a 64 bit process

Tags: c++, linux, windows, unix, memory-management

This question concerns a program that I am developping for.

I am working on a project that requires that sets of rows or a row larger than 2GB aren't sent over the network (the network can't send data in groups larger than 2GB). I have made all of the proper changes to the code so it won't send this/these group(s) but now I am trying to build test cases.

I have already built a test that creates just less than 1 billion rows that occupy more than 2 GB's. The program properly filters out these group of rows before they are sent over the network.

The problem I am running into is that I need to create a single row that will hold a column with a single string  or a collection of columns, inside that row, that hold strings, where the size of this row is larger than `2GB`. But When the string(s) start to occupy close to `2GB`, malloc returns `NULL`.

I did some research and found out that it is probably the fact that I don't have enough contiguous memory, so I started adding more columns with smaller strings. I have gone as far as breaking up the `2GB` string across 64 columns so that it won't have to allocate as much all at once. I am still running into the same problem though and I am getting suspicious that I am overlooking something.

It is a 64 process on a 64 bit Windows 7 system.
8GB of ram. (But I have also tested it on a 64 bit red hat machine with 24GB RAM)

Does anyone have any insight into why the System won't allocate the program memory as it approaches `2GB`?

P.S. I also looked into the memory each process can alloc on a 64 bit system and it was over `100TB`. Considering it is so much, the fact that I can't allocate as I approach 2GB really confuses me.

Comment: Are you using a large enough integer type for storing the sizes? And I assume that you are running a 64 bit OS, not just 64 bit hardware?

Comment: oh true, yes they are 64 bit operating systems that I have tried this on.
@ThomasPadron-McCarthy I'm just looking into the sizes right now. That's a good observation

Comment: Ok so it turns out it is an `unsigned __int64` So I get this feeling that I'm not even getting close to overflowing that integer :p

Comment: Can you post a minimal, compilable program that still exhibits this behavior? My short test program works for me, on my 64-bit Linux with 24 GB RAM. (Or did you see this problem in Windows only?)

Comment: Are you sure you [configured correctly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9yb4317s.aspx)?

Comment: which compiler and IDE are you using?

Comment: My machine certainly allows more than 2GB (namely 16GB, the same as the size of my RAM, possibly because I don't have a huge amount of swap-space available).

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy I am trying to reproduce as we speak, but I'm not having any luck just making an accumulation of strings larger than 2GB, I'll try actually malloc'ing that much space though

Comment: @andre on windows It is the CL compiler from visual studio 2010 from what I know. On Linux I'm not exactly sure but I think it has something to do with eclipse?

Comment: Just a simple check, but i know with visual studio 2010 you have to set the platform to x64 not Win32. Is it possible the platform is not set correctly?

Comment: @TopGunCoder: Your process is 32-bit. The CL compiler is by default 32-bit native, you have to configure [to get the 64-bit compiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/x4d2c09s.aspx).

Comment: I am going to look into it but from what my boss told me the project configures to 64 when you build it on a 64 system. I hope you are right though. I'm also going to look into this [gcAllowVeryLargeObjects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh285054(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Ok so it seems like things are pointing to the compilers being used. I'm going to scour the builds to see what exactly is going on. If it isn't that I'm curious to see whether the compiler only allows 2gb worth of string allocation total or not... I don't see why it would do that but I'm going to check that as a last resort

Comment: @TopGunCoder: `gcAllowVeryLargeObjects` is for the .NET framework. This is a C++ application, right? I have the same configuration and ran fine with 10GB (although it takes a while to allocate).

Comment: @JesseGood I am initializing the build environment using `vcvarsall.bat amd64`, does "native process" mean that it is running as 32 or 64?

Comment: How about that minimal, compilable program that still exhibits this behavior? Take the time to write it. And if that program doesn't show the error, the problem is somewhere else in your code. If it does, it will be much easier to find out what's wrong.

Comment: @TopGunCoder: 64-bit, `amd64` is the 64-bit native compiler.

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy I looked into trying to reproduce what the code is doing but after reading through it I realized that this trying to recreate the implementation is way beyond the scope of my amateur experience. I'm going to talk to my boss about this more and see what he says. I hope he doesn't end up scrapping the test case, then I'll have to figure this out on my own time because I'm really curious as to what is happening

Comment: @TopGunCoder: No, don't recreate the implementation! Just write a very small program that tries to allocate memory in a way similar to what your real program does. If that works, your problem is probably somewhere else than in memory allocation, and you can stop looking at configurations etc.

Comment: I found out what the problem was! Just before I was about to move on I noticed that someone had changed the variable type, in a previous change, from 32 unsigned to signed. So when this was overflowed by my huge row and passed into the alloc wrapper I had, the negative bit would transfer to the negative bit of the unsigned 64... creating a huge amount of memory that it was trying to allocate!!! Thank you all for you help!! I wouldn't have noticed that subtlety had you guys not posed such thorough suggestions :D:D:D:

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy I actually ended up doing that to make sure it was doing what I think it was. Thanks for all the help!!

Comment: @TopGunCoder Please post the solution as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much exploring of the huge group of code that I was having this problem with, I noticed that the size being passed to the `calloc(uint_64)` was being calculated by a function that returned a signed integer. Since this number was being overflowed, when it was cast by the compiler to `uint_64`, the largest bit was set. Which of course resulted in the calloc trying to  allocate a lot of memory.

There is of course a couple of solutions that are possible:

1. change the return type of the size function to `uint_32` (This would have been too large of a change for my code base, and time limits)
2. cast the result of the size function to `uint_32` before passing it to calloc (the option I chose, to bypass that large allocation temporarily)

I hope this helps someone else eventually,

Dan

Comment: why don't return `size_t` for sizes?